# Groupby order by and dto

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a linq to sql something like

```
var txn = (from t in db.TLI
              where (#some condition1) &&
              (#some condition2)
                      select new Item
                      {
                           staffid = t.table1.table2.ID,
                           date = t.date.Value,
                       }
          )
          .GroupBy(t => t.staffid)
          .ToList();*
```

till here things are working fine but now i want to order within group by say date, how would i do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order items inside each group, you can use Select:

```
.GroupBy(t => t.staffid)
.Select(p => new {p.Key, Items = t.OrderBy(x => x.date).ToList()})
.ToList();
```

Comment: do you mean something like <br>
var txn = (from t in db.TLI
              where (#some condition1) &&
              (#some condition2)
                      select new Item
                      {
                           staffid = t.table1.table2.ID,
                           date = t.date.Value,
                       }
          )
          .GroupBy(t => t.staffid)
          .Select(p => new {p.Key, Items = t.OrderBy(x =>                x.date).ToList()})
.ToList();

But this is making it of anonymous type , i want it to return of type Item only